# Crashlytics iOS Beta stuck in fabric app

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, crashlytics-beta

I'm periodically releasing my beta app to testers with Crashlytics Beta(using Fabric mac app).

Lately Fabric app doesn't proceed after release notes step.

Actually, it goes like

1. Archiving(in xcode)
2. Fabric app detects archived app and opens itself
3. Select testers
4. Release notes
5. Done

In step 4, clicking "Next" button doesn't do anything when I do this first time. It works when archiving the same version again and do the exact same steps, which means I always have to do this two times.

Am I missing something changed? or Is it a fabric(of possibly crashlytics) bug?

Comment: unchecking Run script only when installing worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that it happens only when I launch fabric app manually to process adhoc distribution.
When I do the same with the MacOS's notification showed after archiving the app(adhoc), it doesn't happen.

Update: There's no guarantee..